# How to add text with comma in csv column?

Tags: csv

Explanation;
            I am preparing a csv file to import in my database using php.In which one of my database table field is description.In which i provides the description of my task.So, I have prepared a csv file in which i added a description in one of the column of csv and the description which contains comma(,) and csv treat as different column.

How can i manage in csv while my description is with comma?

Please help me to solve out this problem.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Basic_rules

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the fields enclosed in quotes, like "a, b". And make sure the importer handles this correctly.

Comment: suppose, my string is like husband,wife,brother and parents.how to enclosed this string???

Comment: Is there any editor which do this task?? Any other special character which cause the problem in csv?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in quotes.

example CSV with 4 columns:

```
1,"John","Smiths","admin,moderator,user"
2,"Jack","Brown","user"
3,"Jane","Smiths","moderator,user"
```